# Testing file selection with testing-library in react

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to test a file selection, but the selected file is not returned. fileInput?.files retunes "{}"

```
import { act, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import React from 'react'
import { renderWithProviders } from 'testing/renderWithProviders'

import { FileSelectionDialogContent } from './fileSelectionDialogContent'

test('Show a file selection dialog and test file selection', async () => {
    const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' })

    const rendered = renderWithProviders(<FileSelectionDialogContent onFileSelect={() => {}} />)

    const fileInput = rendered.container.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as HTMLInputElement
    expect(fileInput).not.toBeNull()  // This is OK

    userEvent.upload(fileInput, file)


    console.log('Selected file =====> ', fileInput?.files) // Returnes an empty object {}
})
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: why are you using `act` and `waitFor`? `upload` already uses `act` internally

Comment: I tried with and without, actually the same result. I remove it in the description, thanks. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`upload()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility/#upload) API signature:

```
upload(
    element: HTMLElement,
    fileOrFiles: File | File[],
): Promise<void>
```

So you forgot to `await` the promise.

A working example:

```
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react'


test('Show a file selection dialog and test file selection', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' })
  render(
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="file-uploader">Upload file:</label>
      <input id="file-uploader" type="file" />
    </div>
  )

  const fileInput = screen.getByLabelText(/upload file/i) as HTMLInputElement
  expect(fileInput).toBeInTheDocument();

  await user.upload(fileInput, file);

  expect(fileInput.files).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(fileInput.files?.item(0)).toBe(file);
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75281480/index.test.tsx (21.366 s)
  ✓ Show a file selection dialog and test file selection (168 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        22.362 s, estimated 23 s
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
```